# Pass asp.net listbox items to a textbox

Tags: asp.net

I'm in a Default.aspx.cs class & I want to pass items that are inside a listbox to a textbox. The items in the listbox are not selected. So I'll have a button & when I click it I want the items on the listbox to also show on a text box. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop & iterate over your listbox fetching each item's text/value & appending it to your textbox. On your button click event,

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtItems.Text = "";
        string result ="";
        foreach (ListItem li in lbItems.Items)
        {
            result += li.Value + ",";
        }

        // Remove the trailing comma in the end  
        txtItems.Text = result.Remove(result.LastIndexOf(","),1);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but the code doesn't work, is there another solution maybe?